# How to make jQuery .resize() trigger more than once?

Tags: jquery, resize

I want to add/remove a class depending on screen size. The class is added when I make the screen smaller than 700px, but when I resize the screen over 700 it keeps the class added instead of removing it.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$(window).resize(function() {
  if ($(this).width() < 700) {
  $('.home #secondaryHeader').addClass('fixed');
  } else {
  $('.home #secondaryHeader').removeClass('fixed'); 
  }
});
});
```

Comment: There is no `else` block in your code, i.e. you don't toggle the class name based on the screen size, and why removing the element? Also what's wrong with using CSS Media Queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the class is not removed is because you need to add logic to remove the class:

```js
if ($(this).width() < 700) {
  $('.home #secondaryHeader').addClass('fixed');
  $('#featured header img, #primaryNav').remove();
} else {
  $('.home #secondaryHeader').removeClass('fixed');
}
```

On the other hand, if you are trying to do styling, the better solution is to simply use CSS media queries for handling re-sizing and different screen sizes.

Comment: @vohuman I had pasted wrong code. I realized part of it could be done with a media query. I edited it to what I have (and what the second commenter recommends) but it's not working.

The reason I'm using jquery instead of a media query is because I have a script that shows the menu when you scroll to a certain point, but I want it to just always show when at a small screen size. But the original script cancels that. Or maybe I'm just confused and doing it wrong!